# How to check HTML in a HTTP response?

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

How to effectively check if an HTTP response contains HTML or not in Java? I am making an HTTP connection like shown below:

```
URL url =  new URL(inputURL);
con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
con.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
con.connect();
con.getResponseCode();
```

Is there a way to effectively check if the response contains HTML (and not other resources like image,.css or .js files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a method dedicated to this : [getContentType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29)

On your HttpsURLConnection, it returns the mime type of the received file.

For an HTML file, it would be "text/html".

So you can just check :

```
boolean isHTML = "text/html".equalsIgnoreCase(con.getContentType());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you trust the web server to return the correct content type headers you could just check those - for HTML it should be:

```
Content-type:text/html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check content type from response.

```
    System.out.println(con.getContentType().equals("text/html"));
```